# Scraping from list of urls using selenium and scrapy

Tags: python, csv, selenium, xpath, scrapy

I'm New to scrapy and Python. I'm Trying to scrape from a list of URLs Using Selenium and scrapy. 
I tried this code:

```
class TechstarSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "techstar"
    allowed_domains = ["techstar.com"]
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('pages.txt').readlines()]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TechstarSpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(10)
        resp = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        item = StartupweekendataItem()
        for data in resp.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]'):
            item['Title'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ol/h3/text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Date'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ol/h3/span/text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Judge1'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]/div[2]/h2/text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Judge1FB'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]/div[2]/h2/a[@class="fa fa-facebook font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Judge1Linked'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]/div[2]/h2/a[@class="fa fa-linkedin font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Judge2'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][2]/div[2]/h2/text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Judge2FB'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][2]/div[2]/h2/a[@class="fa fa-facebook font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Judge2Linked'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]/div[2]/h2/a[@class="fa fa-linkedin font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Coach1'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-coaches"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]//h2//text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Coach1FB'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-coaches"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]//a[@class="fa fa-facebook font-18"]//@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Coach1Linked'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-coaches"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]//a[@class="fa fa-linkedin font-18"]//@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Coach2'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-coaches"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][2]//h2//text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Coach2FB'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-coaches"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][2]//a[@class="fa fa-facebook font-18"]//@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Coach2Linked'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-coaches"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][2]//a[@class="fa fa-linkedin font-18"]//@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Organizer1'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-organizers"]/following-sibling::div[2]/div[@class="large-15 columns"]/ul/li[1]/h5/text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Organizer1FB'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-organizers"]/following-sibling::div[2]/div[@class="large-15 columns"]/ul/li[1]/a["fa fa-facebook font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Organizer1Linked'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-organizers"]/following-sibling::div[2]/div[@class="large-15 columns"]/ul/li[1]/a["fa fa-linkedin font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Organizer2'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-organizers"]/following-sibling::div[2]/div[@class="large-15 columns"]/ul/li[2]/h5/text()')[0].extract(),
            item['Organizer2FB'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-organizers"]/following-sibling::div[2]/div[@class="large-15 columns"]/ul/li[2]/a["fa fa-facebook font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Organizer2Linked'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-organizers"]/following-sibling::div[2]/div[@class="large-15 columns"]/ul/li[2]/a["fa fa-linkedin font-18"]/@href')[0].extract(),
            item['Facilitator'] = data.xpath("//h2[contains(string(), 'Facilitators')]/../../following-sibling::div[1]//h2//text()")[0].extract(),
            item['FacilitatorFB'] = data.xpath("//h2[contains(string(), 'Facilitators')]/../../following-sibling::div[1]//a['fa fa-facebook font-18']//@href")[0].extract(),
            item['FacilitatorLinked'] = data.xpath("//h2[contains(string(), 'Facilitators')]/../../following-sibling::div[1]//a['fa fa-linkedin font-18']//@href")[0].extract(),
            item['Staff1'] = data.xpath("//h2[contains(string(), 'Facilitators')]/../../following-sibling::div[3]//h2//text()")[0].extract(),
            item['Staff1FB'] = data.xpath("//h2[contains(string(), 'Facilitators')]/../../following-sibling::div[3]//a[@class'fa fa-facebook font-18']//@href")[0].extract(),
            item['Staff1Linked'] = data.xpath("//h2[contains(string(), 'Facilitators')]/../../following-sibling::div[3]//a[@class='fa fa-linkedin font-18']//@href")[0].extract(),
            yield item
```

Pages.txt Contains list of urls like this:

```
http://communities.techstars.com/spain/madrid/startup-weekend/11425  
http://communities.techstars.com/usa/phlsw/startup-weekend/3334  
http://communities.techstars.com/bolivia/santacruz/startup-weekend/10815
```

But It's throwing this error:

```
2017-11-12 12:38:26 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://communities.techstars.com/bolivia/santacruz/startup-weekend/10815> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/habenn/Projects/Aleksandr/startupweekendata/startupweekendata/spiders/techstar.py", line 53, in parse
    item['Judge1'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]/div[2]/h2/text()')[0].extract(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 61, in __getitem__
    o = super(SelectorList, self).__getitem__(pos)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This Is the output I'm Trying to Achive is:
[image]

**Question**: It is throwing an error, How can i fix that? and The code too long, can you help me simplifying the code? 
Any help Would Be Really Helpful.

Comment: you are getting error at item['Judge1']  it means you are trying to scrap the element which doesn't exist even, you should try to scrap with few urls then gradually see what errors are you getting

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the access to the first element of your selectors list with `[0]`, in more detail the access to the results of the selector `//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]/div[2]/h2/text()` (see error message fourth line from the bottom).

This is your selector for `Judge1`.

Looking at the source code of the first page in your list, I cannot find an element with `id="event-judges"`, so it is not available.

If you want to be able to select items where one or more attributes are missing (e.g. `Judge1`), I'd recommend you use the method `extract_first()` instead of `[0].extract()`.

`extract_first()` will return `None` if your selector did not match any elements or you can define another default value with `extract_first(default='no-judge')`.

For the `Judge1` selector you would use it like this:

```
item['Judge1'] = data.xpath('//*[@id="event-judges"]/following-sibling::div[@class="row"][1]/div[2]/h2/text()').extract_first(),
```